# Javascript Function dont works on dynamically created ImageButton (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Got something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadImageButtons();
    }

    private void LoadImageButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ImageButton myImageButton = new ImageButton();

            myImageButton .ID = i.ToString();
            myImageButton .CssClass = "buttonFieldClass";
            myImageButton .Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(einButton_Click);
            myImageButton .OnClientClick = "toRight(this.id);return false";

            div.Controls.Add(myImageButton);
        }
    }
```

Javascript (Jquery):

```
function toRight(id) {
$("#id").animate({ "left": "+=250px" }, "slow");};
```

and nothing happens (with static controls it works).. So I think something with the ID goes wrong.. Hope u guys can help me ..

Comment: did you try to alert the id that you get inside toRight ?
just to check that you get a value?

Comment: did you check in view source, what written in client side ?

Comment: i am use "return toRight(this.id);" instead of "toRight(this.id);return false"

Comment: yea, i tried alert and I get the Id as well.. return toRight(this.id) dont works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like your problem is this line

```
    myImageButton .OnClientClick = "toRight(this.id);return false";
```

Try changing to:

```
    myImageButton .OnClientClick = "toRight('" + this.id + "');return false";
```

Oh and the proposed Javascript fix is also correct and required!

Comment: it works if I change the controls to a Div.. Seems that you can't animate imagebuttons..

Comment: ImageButton renders as an <input> element in Html which is an inline element... giving it a "display: block" should do it (which is all the DIV is doing)

Comment: ok thx 4 the answer, perhaps I will try it (got now everthing in Divs)

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery like this.

```
function toRight(id) {
    $("#" + id).animate({
        "left": "+=250px"
    }, "slow");
};
```

The string `"#id"` is not the desired selector.
The desired selector is `"#"` concatenated with the variable `"id"`

Comment: thx 4 answer, but its still not moving.. i just click on the button, but nothing happens, there is also not a postback, (which is good I think)

Comment: ok think know why.. I cant move Imagebuttons, but Divs work ?! :(